# How to stop Silverlight Control Toolkit PieChart from using random colours in its palette?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I'm using SL Toolkit 4's pie chart control on a page. Each time I update the pie chart, they are redrawn with different colours chosen from its palette. How can I get the pie chart to redraw the control with the same set of colours each time it redraws itself?

Comment: Nope. It still does the same thing.

Comment: I looked trough the code of the toolkit using .NET reflector and there's an enumerator used to determine the next palette item, but I wasn't able to create a lightwheight implementation removing this behaviour without beeing too hacky.

Comment: Hmm, I gave up on the control a while back. Sometimes you just have to buy a 3rd party control. This would be one such instance. :)